# AWS - is it possible to pass the parameters from AWS lambda function to AWS sagemaker notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am beginner to AWS console. I am facing issues while building Machine Learning pipeline.

Currently, The Lambda function does the job of getting the uploaded filename, username from front end and invoking the notebook instance.

Also, life cycle configuration at the instance will invoke the notebook for training. So the question is how to pass above variables variables to sagemaker notebook for training the machine learning model. Is it possible to achieve this? Thank you.

```
#invoke command from lambda
client.start_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName='<sagemaker_instance_name>')
```

Lifecycle configuration under sagemaker instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

ENVIRONMENT=JupyterSystemEnv
#JupyterSystemEnv
NOTEBOOK_FILE=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/XGBoost_training.ipynb

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"

nohup jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --to notebook --execute "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" &
```

Comment: Could you share more details on what is that you'd like to achieve? The command you're using only starts a notebook instance, perhaps you'd like to perform a processing job or a training one.

Comment: I have front end where user will upload the .csv file and following functions are get invoked.
1. Once the "submit" button is clicked, the data will sit in s3 bucket.

2. The lambda function will invoke and collect the userid, bucket name and .csv file name.

3. The above lambda function will invoke one more lambda function which invokes the sagemaker instance.

4. The sagemaker instance has lifecycle configuration, which will run the notebook and create endpoint.

But I am unable to send the user id, .csv file, bucket name to the sagemaker notebok.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Found any solution?